# How to cut till first delimiter and get remaining part of strings?

Tags: bash, text-processing

How to cut till first delimiter `/` and get remaining part of strings?

Ex:

```
pandi/sha/Dev/bin/boot
```

I want to cut `pandi`, so the output like

```
sha/Dev/bin/boot
```

Comment: What should be the output for an input like `/full/path` or `//host/path` or `dir/` or `file-path-with-no-slash`?

Comment: You didn't mention what tool you wanted to use for cutting. And there is no "till" in your source string to cut, so your question is confusing. Did you mean "'til", "until", or "up to", instead?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Simply with `cut` command:

```
echo "pandi/sha/Dev/bin/boot" | cut -d'/' -f2-
sha/Dev/bin/boot
```

---

- `-d'/'` - field delimiter
- `-f2-` - a range of fields to output (`-f<from>-<to>` ; in our case: from `2` to the last)

Answer (score 27):

Using [`shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
string="pandi/sha/Dev/bin/boot"
echo "${string#*/}"
```